# Perl Net::Nslookup Module not working?

Tags: perl, nslookup

What I thought would be a pretty basic module to use isn't making sense to me...

Here's my very basic script that isn't returning anything:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Nslookup;

my $prefix = "";
$prefix = $ARGV[0];
my $host = $prefix . "01" . ".company.com";
print "Host: $host\n\n";

my @test = ();
@test = nslookup "$host";
print "@test\n";
```

When I do an nslookup straight from the command line, it gives me the usual output.  This gives me nothing.

What am I not understanding about this?  I've looked at cpan's site: http://search.cpan.org/~darren/Net-Nslookup-2.02/lib/Net/Nslookup.pm but that's not helping me because I'm trying to do exactly what it shows, but to no avail...

Comment: Please, please, please stop calling it "PERL". This is so wrong.

Comment: Will do.  Now onto the question...

Comment: Maybe you want a `.` (dot) before `01`? This works for me when I use it to look up www.google.com

Comment: No that's a part of the prefix.  I will be doing an nslookup on prefix01.company.com, prefix02.company.com, prefix03.company.com, etc etc etc.

Comment: Does that mean do this?: nslookup(debug => 1);

Comment: It means `nslookup( domain => $host, debug => 1);`

Comment: Huh....and now all of a sudden it works?  Strange. But great, I guess I'm all set!  Something changed something and I'm good to go.  thank you all!